# I can't install R package 'Peptides' from CRAN in R version 4.1.1

Tags: r, install.packages

I tried to install the package 'Peptides' from the CRAN using `install.packages("peptides", dependency=TRUE)`, but my R version gave me the following messages:

```
*Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Gebruiker/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘peptides’ is not available for this version of R'*.
```

However, the R version I am using is 4.1.1 and for as far as I'm aware it is the latest version, meaning all 'older' packages should be compatible. Does anyone know what I could do? I am really new to R and definetely not a coding savante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `install.packages("Peptides", dependency=TRUE)`. I think it is because it is capitalized :)